# Transformar las string en posts interactivas: ¿Cómo ampliarlas String con un clic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dash

Tengo un buscador que me devuelve un array `articles` que contiene una articulos.

Sin embargo me gustaria darle un poco más de diseño de cable de noticias de Twitter. También me gustaría poder hacer clic en él y ampliar.

Aqui esta el callback del buscador:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc

import pickle

from ..server import app

@app.callback(
    Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('input-box', 'value')])
def update_search(n_clicks, value):
    f = pickle.load(open("dashboard/data-mm/google-nlu.p", "rb"))
    # let's filter f according to value
    articles = []
    for article in f:
        if value in article['headline']:
            # We want to print this
            articles.append(article)
    print(articles[0])
    return dcc.Markdown([f"{article['headline']}\n" for article in articles])
```

Y aqui esta mi `app.py`:

```
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Tabs(
            [
                dcc.Tab(
                    label='Search article',
                    value= 'search',
                    children = article_search()
                )
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Por lo momento se parece a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada linea negra esta un `article['headline']`. Aqui esta `articles[0]`:

```
{'headline': this is the headline', 'body': 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.', 'sentiment': -0.4000000059604645, 'topics': {'/Finance': 0.6600000262260437}, 'topics_kw': ['Politics', 'The financial sector', 'Media', 'Society', 'Social projects'], 'date': datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 25, 0, 0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias revisar la libreria dash-bootstrap-components, ahi esta la clase collapse la cual le sirve para lo que necesita https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/l/components/collapse.

Podria cambiar esto:

```
return dcc.Markdown([f"{article['headline']}\n" for article in articles])
```

por esto :

```
return [dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader(
            html.H2(
                dbc.Button(
                    f"{articles[position]['headline']}\n",
                    color="link",
                    id=f"group-{position}-toggle",
                )
            )
        ),
        dbc.Collapse(
            dbc.CardBody(f"{articles[position]['body']}"),
            id=f"collapse-{position}",
        ),
    ]
)  for position in range(len(articles))]
```

Eso retornara la lista de articulos como tabs, ademas a tu 'output-container-button' agregar className="accordion" el problema que surge es sus objetos son dinamicos, lo cual Dash no soporta, ya que necesita los id ya indicados para poder  usar los callbacks.

Pero en estos momentos esta en desarrollo los WildCard (actualice su version de dash) que permitiria usar inputs dinamicos con el siguiente codigo :

```
@app.callback(Output('collapse-{*n:d}', 'is_open'),
          [Input('group-{*n:d}-toggle', 'n_clicks')],
          [State('collapse-{*n:d}', 'is_open')])
def toggle_items( item, is_open):
    if item!=None:
        return not is open
```

En caso de que sea solo para visualizar como desarrollo, entonces use Dropdow de la siguiente manera:

```
return [dbc.DropdownMenu(
[

    html.P(articles[position]['body'],className="text-muted px-4 mt-4",
    ),
],
label=articles[position]['headline'],) for position in range(len(articles))]
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Lo probé con el `DropdownMenu`, pero por el momento el cuerpo se muestra con la cabeza. Cuando elimino el array que se devuelve (`html.P(articles[position]['body'],className="text-muted px-4 mt-4"`) ya no tengo este problema, pero cuando hago clic, no aparece nada.

No entendí bien la diferencia entre Dropdown

Comment: El Dropdown es una clase que no necesita que tú crees el callback para desplegar, si estás usando solo la línea que me enviaste falta que indiques la opción Dropdown y el label, ya que el label es el texto que al pulsar desplegará la informacion